# Spring Kafka Consumer KafkaListenerErrorHandler vs ErrorHandler. What is the difference?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the roles and responsibilities of KafkaListenerErrorHandler and ErrorHandler. Here is my understanding of each one of these so far. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Assumption:** Using default Spring Kafka configuration out of the box.

**KafkaListenerErrorHandler**

- This handler gets invoked whenever an exception occurs in a method annotated with @KafkaListener. According to the documentation, this occurs on the listener level.

**ErrorHandler**

- This handler gets invoked whenever an exception is thrown at the container level. This will commit the offset (since by default isAckAfterHandle() returns true) after handling the error (which is simply a log message).

**My confusions**

- Why there is a separate KafkaListenerErrorHandler since we already have the ErrorHandler on a container level and a listener belongs to a container?
- Does this mean when we use @KafkaListener annotation, the error is never handled by the ErrorHandler on the container level rather handled by the KafkaListenerErrorHandler on the listener level?
- If ErrorHandler on the container level never gets invoked when using @KafkaListener annotation, then how do the offsets get committed? Is KafkaListenerErrorHandler responsible for that? How many times does a KafkaListenerErrorHandler will retry a failed message?
- How does Retry/Recovery work for KafkaListenerErrorHandler?

Answer (score 1):

The `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` is mostly used for request/reply scenarios - it allows sending some error indication as the result to the caller, but returning some value.

It could also be used, for example, to log the converted `Message<?>` and re-throw the exception so the container error handler (which now defaults to a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`) can handle the exception. The container error handler does not have access to the converted message.

If the listener error handler does not rethrow the exception, then retry is cancelled.

Retry in the adapter is deprecated in favor of the container error handler because, now, the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` supports back off, exception classification etc.

Comment: Does that imply that if KafkaListenerErrorHandler  doesn't throw an exception back to the container, then the offset will be committed and next message in the topic will be received by the method annotated with @KafkaListener?

Comment: Yes; that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A follow up question is does out of the box Spring Configuration throw an exception via KafkaListenerErrorHandler when there is an error processing the message from the method annotated with @KafkaListener? In my head it has to be doing that since I have definitely seen retries happening in logs and like you said retries can't be happening if the listener error handler doesn't throw exception.

Comment: There is no listener error handler by default so any exception thrown by the listener is thrown to the container.

Comment: Does that mean to provide a listener error handler for a listener annotated with @KafkaListener, we have to configure the KafkaListenerErrorHandler since by default there is no listener error handler?

Comment: Yes; but as I said, it is for specific use cases only. It is not required.